# Что из себя представляла спецификация HTML IE1?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, спецификация

Странный вопрос, но если можете то напишите спецификацию `Internet Explorer 1`,  а именно HTML и CSS (если он вообще был).

Comment: CSS поддерживался начиная с IE3

Comment: Значит     HTML    .............

Comment: В англоязчной статье на Википедии пишут, что там поддерживались таблицы. Но пруфов нет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Начнем с того, что Microsoft начала разработку Internet Explorer с лицензирования другого браузера, Spyglass Mosaic (на тот момент наиболее передовой разработки, которая и сделала web тем, чем мы пользуемся сегодня). Сам браузер был основан на библиотеке libwww и поддерживал достаточно широкий набор протоколов Archie, FTP, gopher, HTTP, NNTP, telnet, WAIS.

Самая первая версия Internet Explorer включала только поддержку базового рендеринга таблицы HTML (DOM). Вторая версия уже имела поддержку JavaScript, NNTP, фреймов и SSL. Каскадные таблицы стилей (CSS) стали доступны только с выходом третьей версии Internet Explorer.